# Pre-Render AmChart as image for later use

Tags: spring, amcharts

I am using AmCharts and am wondering if there is a way i can render a AmChart into say image or even buffer for later processing.

The idea is to be able to export a number of charts in a single PDF document which would also have custom content pertaining to charts (e.g. detailed explanations of charts, interpretations of data, executive summaries etc.)

Currently i use Spring MVC for my applications, and AmCharts for my graphing data.

Comment: Take a look at something like PhantomJS. http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/automate-report-generation-using-phantomjs/

Comment: Thanks @martynasma i'll check it out